# Deregistering jQuery breaks Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using WordPress and Gravity Forms. When I deregister jQuery, `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` it seems Gravity Forms doesn't want to include the scripts needed. I am deregistering and including my own jQuery in the footer.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/jquery.json.min.js?ver=2.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/gravityforms.min.js?ver=2.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js?ver=2.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/js/placeholders.jquery.min.js?ver=2.3.2'></script>
```

The above scripts are completely missing when I deregister jQuery, and appear again when I don't deregister.

Is there a way I can keep jQuery deregistered while including these scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Try to deregister the wp jQuery first and then register your own required version the wp way.

```
function my_enqueued_assets() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-your-version.min.js', array(), '2.2.3' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_assets' );
```

The third argument in `wp_enqueue_script`  are the dependencies of the script. If the dependencies aren't loaded the script it self won't load either.

Comment: I agree your answer works, but the issue is that I want to add my own inline jquery into the footer.

Comment: You can try using `wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery', '//');` you will end up with an 404 script tag though.  Why do you want to hardcode it? You know you can use the `in_footer` parameter right?

Comment: im just experimenting with things to increase pagespeed

Comment: Allright. I use Autoptimize for that and i am really happy about it. Just a simple tool to concat all scripts and place them in your footer.